# Using iTextSharp v4.1.2, how do I add an image to the header?

Tags: itext

I can add a text header in iTextSharp v4.1.2 but how do I add an image instead of text? I am currently using a text header but I would like to replace it with an image.

```
    ' Create a Document object
    Dim doc As Document = New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
    doc.SetMargins(pageMarginLeft, pageMarginRight, pageMarginTopBottom, pageMarginTopBottom)

    ' Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)

    ' Set header and footer
    Dim headerFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLUE)
    Dim header As New HeaderFooter(New Paragraph("VOLUNTEER MASTER SCHEDULE", headerFont), False)

    Dim footerFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)
    Dim footer As New HeaderFooter(New Phrase("Page: ", footerFont), True)
    doc.Header = header
    doc.Footer = footer

    ' Open the Document for writing
    doc.Open()
```

Comment: If you don't show how you are doing it now, we can hardly tell you what to do differently.

Comment: Moreover, you're using a version that is no longer supported, so please don't expect support.

Comment: I'm using the older version due to licensing (MPL vs AGPL).